# How to make scrollable menu with flexbox column in bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, flexbox, megamenu

I created a menu using Bootstrap. I don't want the content to overflow in the column mode and be automatically moved down after reaching the end of the menu. The submenus of this megamenu have variable heights, which is why I want to use the column flex property.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CiAZE.jpg)

i want the output to be like below image :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SBqsW.jpg)

this is my megamenu code :

```css
.dropdown-menu.show {
    left: 0 !important;
    right: 0 !important;
    max-height: 260px;
    flex-direction: column;
    display: flex;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>



<ul class="nav nav-pills">
  <li class="nav-item dropdown position-static">
    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown</a>
    <div class="border dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-md-right py-2 shadow" aria-labelledby="bd-versions2">
                                <div class="row mx-0">
                                    
                                    <div class="col-12">
                                            <div class="align-content-between align-items-center flex-column row" style="max-height: 288px;">
                                                <div class="col-sm-2">
                                                    <ul class="tpcategory px-0">
                                                        <li class="dropdown-header p-2">JAVA</li>
                                                        <li class="dropdown-divider m-0"></li>
                                                        <li class="mega-menu-subcategory"><a href="text-category.php">Language Fundamentals</a></li>
                                                        <li class="mega-menu-subcategory"><a href="#">Window Form</a></li>
                                                        <li class="mega-menu-subcategory"><a href="#">.Net Framework</a></li>
                                                        <li class="mega-menu-subcategory"><a href="#">LINQ</a></li>
                                                        <li class="mega-menu-subcategory"><a href="#">ADO.NET</a></li>
                                                        <li class="mega-menu-subcategory"><a href="#">Refrence</a></li>
                                                    </ul>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="col-sm-2">
                                                    <ul class="tpcategory px-0">
                                                        <li class="dropdown-header p-2">JAVA</li>
                                                        <li class="dropdown-divider m-0"></li>
                                                        <li class="mega-menu-subcategory"><a href="text-category.php">Language Fundamentals</a></li>
                                                        <li class="mega-menu-subcategory"><a href="#">Window Form</a></li>
                                                        <li class="mega-menu-subcategory"><a href="#">.Net Framework</a></li>
                                                        <li class="mega-menu-subcategory"><a href="#">LINQ</a></li>
                                                        <li class="mega-menu-subcategory"><a href="#">ADO.NET</a></li>
                                                        <li class="mega-menu-subcategory"><a href="#">Refrence</a></li>
                                                    </ul>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="col-sm-2">
                                                    <ul class="tpcategory px-0">
                                                        <li class="dropdown-header p-2">JAVA</li>
                                                        <li class="dropdown-divider m-0"></li>
                                                        <li class="mega-menu-subcategory"><a href="text-category.php">Language Fundamentals</a></li>
                                                        <li class="mega-menu-subcategory"><a href="#">Window Form</a></li>
                                                        <li class="mega-menu-subcategory"><a href="#">.Net Framework</a></li>
                                                        <li class="mega-menu-subcategory"><a href="#">LINQ</a></li>
                                                        <li class="mega-menu-subcategory"><a href="#">ADO.NET</a></li>
                                                        <li class="mega-menu-subcategory"><a href="#">Refrence</a></li>
                                                    </ul>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="col-sm-2">
                                                    <ul class="tpcategory px-0">
                                                        <li class="dropdown-header p-2">JAVA</li>
                                                        <li class="dropdown-divider m-0"></li>
                                                        <li class="mega-menu-subcategory"><a href="text-category.php">Language Fundamentals</a></li>
                                                        <li class="mega-menu-subcategory"><a href="#">Window Form</a></li>
                                                        <li class="mega-menu-subcategory"><a href="#">.Net Framework</a></li>
                                                        <li class="mega-menu-subcategory"><a href="#">LINQ</a></li>
                                                        <li class="mega-menu-subcategory"><a href="#">ADO.NET</a></li>
                                                        <li class="mega-menu-subcategory"><a href="#">Refrence</a></li>
                                                    </ul>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="col-sm-2">
                                                    <ul class="tpcategory px-0">
                                                        <li class="dropdown-header p-2">JAVA</li>
                                                        <li class="dropdown-divider m-0"></li>
                                                        <li class="mega-menu-subcategory"><a href="text-category.php">Language Fundamentals</a></li>
                                                        <li class="mega-menu-subcategory"><a href="#">Window Form</a></li>
                                                        <li class="mega-menu-subcategory"><a href="#">.Net Framework</a></li>
                                                        <li class="mega-menu-subcategory"><a href="#">LINQ</a></li>
                                                        <li class="mega-menu-subcategory"><a href="#">ADO.NET</a></li>
                                                        <li class="mega-menu-subcategory"><a href="#">Refrence</a></li>
                                                    </ul>
                                                </div>
                                            <div class="col-sm-2">
                                                <ul class="tpcategory px-0">
                                                    <li class="dropdown-header p-2">++C</li>
                                                    <li class="dropdown-divider m-0"></li>
                                                    <li class="mega-menu-subcategory"><a href="#">Language Fundamentals</a></li>
                                                    <li class="mega-menu-subcategory"><a href="#">String and Date</a></li>
                                                <li class="mega-menu-subcategory"><a href="#">Language Fundamentals</a></li></ul>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-sm-2">
                                                <ul class="tpcategory px-0">
                                                    <li class="dropdown-header p-2">PHP</li>
                                                    <li class="dropdown-divider m-0"></li>
                                                    <li class="mega-menu-subcategory"><a href="#">Language Fundamentals</a></li>
                                                    <li class="mega-menu-subcategory"><a href="#">Cookie &amp; Session</a></li>
                                                    <li class="mega-menu-subcategory"><a href="#">Date And Time</a></li>
                                                </ul>
                                            </div>              
                                            <div class="col-sm-2">
                                                <ul class="tpcategory px-0">
                                                    <li class="dropdown-header p-2">Python</li>
                                                    <li class="dropdown-divider m-0"></li>
                                                    <li class="mega-menu-subcategory"><a href="#">Language Fundamentals</a></li>
                                                    <li class="mega-menu-subcategory"><a href="#">Tkinter</a></li>
                                                    <li class="mega-menu-subcategory"><a href="#">Databse</a></li>
                                                </ul>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-sm-2">
                                                <ul class="tpcategory px-0">
                                                    <li class="dropdown-header p-2">Kotlin</li>
                                                    <li class="dropdown-divider m-0"></li>
                                                    <li class="mega-menu-subcategory"><a href="#">Language Fundamentals</a></li>
                                                </ul>
                                            </div>
                                        <div class="col-sm-2">
                                                <ul class="tpcategory px-0">
                                                    <li class="dropdown-header p-2">Kotlin</li>
                                                    <li class="dropdown-divider m-0"></li>
                                                    <li class="mega-menu-subcategory"><a href="#">Language Fundamentals</a></li>
                                                </ul>
                                            </div><div class="col-sm-2">
                                                <ul class="tpcategory px-0">
                                                    <li class="dropdown-header p-2">Kotlin</li>
                                                    <li class="dropdown-divider m-0"></li>
                                                    <li class="mega-menu-subcategory"><a href="#">Language Fundamentals</a></li>
                                                </ul>
                                            </div><div class="col-sm-2">
                                                <ul class="tpcategory px-0">
                                                    <li class="dropdown-header p-2">Kotlin</li>
                                                    <li class="dropdown-divider m-0"></li>
                                                    <li class="mega-menu-subcategory"><a href="#">Language Fundamentals</a></li>
                                                </ul>
                                            </div></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Hi, the current codes provided doesn't look like your picture posted. Can you please post a complete code for your menu? Thanks.

Comment: @yinsweet thanks, i edited the question, now the snippet code is the right one , please run it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made the following code changes to make the scrollable menu.

```
<!-- Remove align-content-between align-items-center flex-column  -->
<!-- Add overflow-y: auto; overflow-x: hidden; -->
<!-- Change "max-height: 288px;" to "max-height: 250px;"-->
<div class="row" style="max-height: 250px; overflow-y: auto; overflow-x: hidden;">
```

```css
.dropdown-menu.show {
  left: 0 !important;
  right: 0 !important;
  max-height: 260px;
  flex-direction: column;
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>



<ul class="nav nav-pills">
  <li class="nav-item dropdown position-static">
    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown</a>
    <div class="border dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-md-right py-2 shadow" aria-labelledby="bd-versions2">
      <div class="row mx-0">

        <div class="col-12">
          <!-- Remove align-content-between align-items-center flex-column  -->
          <!-- Add overflow-y: auto; overflow-x: hidden; -->
          <!-- Change "max-height: 288px;" to "max-height: 250px;"-->
          <div class="row" style="max-height: 250px; overflow-y: auto; overflow-x: hidden;">
            <div class="col-sm-2">
              <ul class="tpcategory px-0">
                <li class="dropdown-header p-2">JAVA</li>
                <li class="dropdown-divider m-0"></li>
                <li class="mega-menu-subcategory"><a href="text-category.php">Language Fundamentals</a></li>
                <li class="mega-menu-subcategory"><a href="#">Window Form</a></li>
                <li class="mega-menu-subcategory"><a href="#">.Net Framework</a></li>
                <li class="mega-menu-subcategory"><a href="#">LINQ</a></li>
                <li class="mega-menu-subcategory"><a href="#">ADO.NET</a></li>
                <li class="mega-menu-subcategory"><a href="#">Refrence</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-2">
              <ul class="tpcategory px-0">
                <li class="dropdown-header p-2">JAVA</li>
                <li class="dropdown-divider m-0"></li>
                <li class="mega-menu-subcategory"><a href="text-category.php">Language Fundamentals</a></li>
                <li class="mega-menu-subcategory"><a href="#">Window Form</a></li>
                <li class="mega-menu-subcategory"><a href="#">.Net Framework</a></li>
                <li class="mega-menu-subcategory"><a href="#">LINQ</a></li>
                <li class="mega-menu-subcategory"><a href="#">ADO.NET</a></li>
                <li class="mega-menu-subcategory"><a href="#">Refrence</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-2">
              <ul class="tpcategory px-0">
                <li class="dropdown-header p-2">JAVA</li>
                <li class="dropdown-divider m-0"></li>
                <li class="mega-menu-subcategory"><a href="text-category.php">Language Fundamentals</a></li>
                <li class="mega-menu-subcategory"><a href="#">Window Form</a></li>
                <li class="mega-menu-subcategory"><a href="#">.Net Framework</a></li>
                <li class="mega-menu-subcategory"><a href="#">LINQ</a></li>
                <li class="mega-menu-subcategory"><a href="#">ADO.NET</a></li>
                <li class="mega-menu-subcategory"><a href="#">Refrence</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-2">
              <ul class="tpcategory px-0">
                <li class="dropdown-header p-2">JAVA</li>
                <li class="dropdown-divider m-0"></li>
                <li class="mega-menu-subcategory"><a href="text-category.php">Language Fundamentals</a></li>
                <li class="mega-menu-subcategory"><a href="#">Window Form</a></li>
                <li class="mega-menu-subcategory"><a href="#">.Net Framework</a></li>
                <li class="mega-menu-subcategory"><a href="#">LINQ</a></li>
                <li class="mega-menu-subcategory"><a href="#">ADO.NET</a></li>
                <li class="mega-menu-subcategory"><a href="#">Refrence</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-2">
              <ul class="tpcategory px-0">
                <li class="dropdown-header p-2">JAVA</li>
                <li class="dropdown-divider m-0"></li>
                <li class="mega-menu-subcategory"><a href="text-category.php">Language Fundamentals</a></li>
                <li class="mega-menu-subcategory"><a href="#">Window Form</a></li>
                <li class="mega-menu-subcategory"><a href="#">.Net Framework</a></li>
                <li class="mega-menu-subcategory"><a href="#">LINQ</a></li>
                <li class="mega-menu-subcategory"><a href="#">ADO.NET</a></li>
                <li class="mega-menu-subcategory"><a href="#">Refrence</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-2">
              <ul class="tpcategory px-0">
                <li class="dropdown-header p-2">++C</li>
                <li class="dropdown-divider m-0"></li>
                <li class="mega-menu-subcategory"><a href="#">Language Fundamentals</a></li>
                <li class="mega-menu-subcategory"><a href="#">String and Date</a></li>
                <li class="mega-menu-subcategory"><a href="#">Language Fundamentals</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-2">
              <ul class="tpcategory px-0">
                <li class="dropdown-header p-2">PHP</li>
                <li class="dropdown-divider m-0"></li>
                <li class="mega-menu-subcategory"><a href="#">Language Fundamentals</a></li>
                <li class="mega-menu-subcategory"><a href="#">Cookie &amp; Session</a></li>
                <li class="mega-menu-subcategory"><a href="#">Date And Time</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-2">
              <ul class="tpcategory px-0">
                <li class="dropdown-header p-2">Python</li>
                <li class="dropdown-divider m-0"></li>
                <li class="mega-menu-subcategory"><a href="#">Language Fundamentals</a></li>
                <li class="mega-menu-subcategory"><a href="#">Tkinter</a></li>
                <li class="mega-menu-subcategory"><a href="#">Databse</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-2">
              <ul class="tpcategory px-0">
                <li class="dropdown-header p-2">Kotlin</li>
                <li class="dropdown-divider m-0"></li>
                <li class="mega-menu-subcategory"><a href="#">Language Fundamentals</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-2">
              <ul class="tpcategory px-0">
                <li class="dropdown-header p-2">Kotlin</li>
                <li class="dropdown-divider m-0"></li>
                <li class="mega-menu-subcategory"><a href="#">Language Fundamentals</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-2">
              <ul class="tpcategory px-0">
                <li class="dropdown-header p-2">Kotlin</li>
                <li class="dropdown-divider m-0"></li>
                <li class="mega-menu-subcategory"><a href="#">Language Fundamentals</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-2">
              <ul class="tpcategory px-0">
                <li class="dropdown-header p-2">Kotlin</li>
                <li class="dropdown-divider m-0"></li>
                <li class="mega-menu-subcategory"><a href="#">Language Fundamentals</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

EDIT 1: Remove `overflow-x`, `overflow-y` and `max-height: 250px;` styles and remove the `max-height` in `.dropdown-menu.show`

```
<!-- Remove align-content-between align-items-center flex-column  -->
<!-- Remove overflow-y: auto; overflow-x: hidden; -->
<!-- Remove "max-height: 250px;"-->
<div class="row">
```

```css
.dropdown-menu.show {
  left: 0 !important;
  right: 0 !important;
  /* max-height: 260px; */
  flex-direction: column;
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>



<ul class="nav nav-pills">
  <li class="nav-item dropdown position-static">
    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown</a>
    <div class="border dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-md-right py-2 shadow" aria-labelledby="bd-versions2">
      <div class="row mx-0">

        <div class="col-12">
          <!-- Remove align-content-between align-items-center flex-column  -->
          <!-- Remove overflow-y: auto; overflow-x: hidden; -->
          <!-- Remove "max-height: 250px;"-->
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-2">
              <ul class="tpcategory px-0">
                <li class="dropdown-header p-2">JAVA</li>
                <li class="dropdown-divider m-0"></li>
                <li class="mega-menu-subcategory"><a href="text-category.php">Language Fundamentals</a></li>
                <li class="mega-menu-subcategory"><a href="#">Window Form</a></li>
                <li class="mega-menu-subcategory"><a href="#">.Net Framework</a></li>
                <li class="mega-menu-subcategory"><a href="#">LINQ</a></li>
                <li class="mega-menu-subcategory"><a href="#">ADO.NET</a></li>
                <li class="mega-menu-subcategory"><a href="#">Refrence</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-2">
              <ul class="tpcategory px-0">
                <li class="dropdown-header p-2">JAVA</li>
                <li class="dropdown-divider m-0"></li>
                <li class="mega-menu-subcategory"><a href="text-category.php">Language Fundamentals</a></li>
                <li class="mega-menu-subcategory"><a href="#">Window Form</a></li>
                <li class="mega-menu-subcategory"><a href="#">.Net Framework</a></li>
                <li class="mega-menu-subcategory"><a href="#">LINQ</a></li>
                <li class="mega-menu-subcategory"><a href="#">ADO.NET</a></li>
                <li class="mega-menu-subcategory"><a href="#">Refrence</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-2">
              <ul class="tpcategory px-0">
                <li class="dropdown-header p-2">JAVA</li>
                <li class="dropdown-divider m-0"></li>
                <li class="mega-menu-subcategory"><a href="text-category.php">Language Fundamentals</a></li>
                <li class="mega-menu-subcategory"><a href="#">Window Form</a></li>
                <li class="mega-menu-subcategory"><a href="#">.Net Framework</a></li>
                <li class="mega-menu-subcategory"><a href="#">LINQ</a></li>
                <li class="mega-menu-subcategory"><a href="#">ADO.NET</a></li>
                <li class="mega-menu-subcategory"><a href="#">Refrence</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-2">
              <ul class="tpcategory px-0">
                <li class="dropdown-header p-2">JAVA</li>
                <li class="dropdown-divider m-0"></li>
                <li class="mega-menu-subcategory"><a href="text-category.php">Language Fundamentals</a></li>
                <li class="mega-menu-subcategory"><a href="#">Window Form</a></li>
                <li class="mega-menu-subcategory"><a href="#">.Net Framework</a></li>
                <li class="mega-menu-subcategory"><a href="#">LINQ</a></li>
                <li class="mega-menu-subcategory"><a href="#">ADO.NET</a></li>
                <li class="mega-menu-subcategory"><a href="#">Refrence</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-2">
              <ul class="tpcategory px-0">
                <li class="dropdown-header p-2">JAVA</li>
                <li class="dropdown-divider m-0"></li>
                <li class="mega-menu-subcategory"><a href="text-category.php">Language Fundamentals</a></li>
                <li class="mega-menu-subcategory"><a href="#">Window Form</a></li>
                <li class="mega-menu-subcategory"><a href="#">.Net Framework</a></li>
                <li class="mega-menu-subcategory"><a href="#">LINQ</a></li>
                <li class="mega-menu-subcategory"><a href="#">ADO.NET</a></li>
                <li class="mega-menu-subcategory"><a href="#">Refrence</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-2">
              <ul class="tpcategory px-0">
                <li class="dropdown-header p-2">++C</li>
                <li class="dropdown-divider m-0"></li>
                <li class="mega-menu-subcategory"><a href="#">Language Fundamentals</a></li>
                <li class="mega-menu-subcategory"><a href="#">String and Date</a></li>
                <li class="mega-menu-subcategory"><a href="#">Language Fundamentals</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-2">
              <ul class="tpcategory px-0">
                <li class="dropdown-header p-2">PHP</li>
                <li class="dropdown-divider m-0"></li>
                <li class="mega-menu-subcategory"><a href="#">Language Fundamentals</a></li>
                <li class="mega-menu-subcategory"><a href="#">Cookie &amp; Session</a></li>
                <li class="mega-menu-subcategory"><a href="#">Date And Time</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-2">
              <ul class="tpcategory px-0">
                <li class="dropdown-header p-2">Python</li>
                <li class="dropdown-divider m-0"></li>
                <li class="mega-menu-subcategory"><a href="#">Language Fundamentals</a></li>
                <li class="mega-menu-subcategory"><a href="#">Tkinter</a></li>
                <li class="mega-menu-subcategory"><a href="#">Databse</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-2">
              <ul class="tpcategory px-0">
                <li class="dropdown-header p-2">Kotlin</li>
                <li class="dropdown-divider m-0"></li>
                <li class="mega-menu-subcategory"><a href="#">Language Fundamentals</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-2">
              <ul class="tpcategory px-0">
                <li class="dropdown-header p-2">Kotlin</li>
                <li class="dropdown-divider m-0"></li>
                <li class="mega-menu-subcategory"><a href="#">Language Fundamentals</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-2">
              <ul class="tpcategory px-0">
                <li class="dropdown-header p-2">Kotlin</li>
                <li class="dropdown-divider m-0"></li>
                <li class="mega-menu-subcategory"><a href="#">Language Fundamentals</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-2">
              <ul class="tpcategory px-0">
                <li class="dropdown-header p-2">Kotlin</li>
                <li class="dropdown-divider m-0"></li>
                <li class="mega-menu-subcategory"><a href="#">Language Fundamentals</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: No, my dear friend, look, I want that if the categories are overflowed from the box, they will be displayed under the rest of the categories (in a new row), they will be hidden in your code, while I want to be in a row.

Comment: Hi, you may remove the overflow-x and overflow-y styles and it will always visible. But then, you might want to change the max-height of the .dropdown-menu.show so that all contents show within the container.

Comment: There is no way to increase height automatically and prevent it from being manipulated manually? I want everything to happen automatically ( without js )

Comment: Remove the max-height and it will be auto. You may see the second code snippet that I made to check if that is your desire output.

Answer (score 0):

i have edited your code you can see it or copy it maybe it can help

```
<div class="nav-item dropdown tuts mega-menu static">
    <!-- <div class="dropdown dropright"> -->
    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="bd-versions2" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            Mega Menu
    </a>
    <div class="border dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-md-right shadow" aria-labelledby="bd-versions2">
            
            
                    <div class="   d-md-flex flex-wrap" >
                        <div style="margin-right: 2%; margin-left: 10px;">
                            <!-- <ul class="tpcategory px-0"> -->
                                <div class="dropdown-header p-2">JAVA</div>
                                <div class="dropdown-divider m-0"></div>
                                <div class="mega-menu-subcategory dropdown-item"><a href="text-category.php">Language Fundamentals</a></div>
                                <div class="mega-menu-subcategory dropdown-item"><a href="#">Window Form</a></div>
                                <div class="mega-menu-subcategory dropdown-item"><a href="#">.Net Framework</a></div>
                                <div class="mega-menu-subcategory dropdown-item"><a href="#">LINQ</a></div>
                                <div class="mega-menu-subcategory dropdown-item"><a href="#">ADO.NET</a></div>
                                <div class="mega-menu-subcategory dropdown-item"><a href="#">Refrence</a></div>
                            <!-- </ul> -->
                        </div>
                        <div style="margin-right: auto;">
                            <!-- <ul class="tpcategory px-0"> -->
                                <div class="dropdown-header p-2">JAVA</div>
                                <div class="dropdown-divider m-0"></div>
                                <div class="mega-menu-subcategory dropdown-item"><a href="text-category.php">Language Fundamentals</a></div>
                                <div class="mega-menu-subcategory dropdown-item"><a href="#">Window Form</a></div>
                                <div class="mega-menu-subcategory dropdown-item"><a href="#">.Net Framework</a></div>
                                <div class="mega-menu-subcategory dropdown-item"><a href="#">LINQ</a></div>
                                <div class="mega-menu-subcategory dropdown-item"><a href="#">ADO.NET</a></div>
                                <div class="mega-menu-subcategory dropdown-item"><a href="#">Refrence</a></div>
                            <!-- </ul> -->
                        </div>
                        <div style="margin-right: auto;">
                            <!-- <ul class="tpcategory px-0"> -->
                                <div class="dropdown-header p-2">JAVA</div>
                                <div class="dropdown-divider m-0"></div>
                                <div class="mega-menu-subcategory dropdown-item"><a href="text-category.php">Language Fundamentals</a></div>
                                <div class="mega-menu-subcategory dropdown-item"><a href="#">Window Form</a></div>
                                <div class="mega-menu-subcategory dropdown-item"><a href="#">.Net Framework</a></div>
                                <div class="mega-menu-subcategory dropdown-item"><a href="#">LINQ</a></div>
                                <div class="mega-menu-subcategory dropdown-item"><a href="#">ADO.NET</a></div>
                                <div class="mega-menu-subcategory dropdown-item"><a href="#">Refrence</a></div>
                            <!-- </ul> -->
                        </div>
                        <div style="margin-right: auto;">
                            <!-- <ul class="tpcategory px-0"> -->
                                <div class="dropdown-header p-2">JAVA</div>
                                <div class="dropdown-divider m-0"></div>
                                <div class="mega-menu-subcategory dropdown-item"><a href="text-category.php">Language Fundamentals</a></div>
                                <div class="mega-menu-subcategory dropdown-item"><a href="#">Window Form</a></div>
                                <div class="mega-menu-subcategory dropdown-item"><a href="#">.Net Framework</a></div>
                                <div class="mega-menu-subcategory dropdown-item"><a href="#">LINQ</a></div>
                                <div class="mega-menu-subcategory dropdown-item"><a href="#">ADO.NET</a></div>
                                <div class="mega-menu-subcategory dropdown-item"><a href="#">Refrence</a></div>
                            <!-- </ul> -->
                        </div>
                        <div style="margin-right: auto;">
                            <!-- <ul class="tpcategory px-0"> -->
                                <div class="dropdown-header p-2">JAVA</div>
                                <div class="dropdown-divider m-0"></div>
                                <div class="mega-menu-subcategory dropdown-item"><a href="text-category.php">Language Fundamentals</a></div>
                                <div class="mega-menu-subcategory dropdown-item"><a href="#">Window Form</a></div>
                                <div class="mega-menu-subcategory dropdown-item"><a href="#">.Net Framework</a></div>
                                <div class="mega-menu-subcategory dropdown-item"><a href="#">LINQ</a></div>
                                <div class="mega-menu-subcategory dropdown-item"><a href="#">ADO.NET</a></div>
                                <div class="mega-menu-subcategory dropdown-item"><a href="#">Refrence</a></div>
                            <!-- </ul> -->
                        </div>
                    <div style="margin-right: auto;">
                        <!-- <ul class="tpcategory px-0"> -->
                            <div class="dropdown-header p-2">++C</div>
                            <div class="dropdown-divider m-0"></div>
                            <div class="mega-menu-subcategory dropdown-item"><a href="#">Language Fundamentals</a></div>
                            <div class="mega-menu-subcategory dropdown-item"><a href="#">String and Date</a></div>
                        <div class="mega-menu-subcategory"><a href="#">Language Fundamentals</a></div>
                    <!-- </ul> -->
                    </div>
                    <div style="margin-right: auto;">
                        <!-- <ul class="tpcategory px-0"> -->
                            <div class="dropdown-header p-2">PHP</div>
                            <div class="dropdown-divider m-0"></div>
                            <div class="mega-menu-subcategory dropdown-item"><a href="#">Language Fundamentals</a></div>
                            <div class="mega-menu-subcategory dropdown-item"><a href="#">Cookie &amp; Session</a></div>
                            <div class="mega-menu-subcategory dropdown-item"><a href="#">Date And Time</a></div>
                        <!-- </ul> -->
                    </div>              
                    <div style="margin-right: auto;">
                        <!-- <ul class="tpcategory px-0"> -->
                            <div class="dropdown-header p-2">Python</div>
                            <div class="dropdown-divider m-0"></div>
                            <div class="mega-menu-subcategory dropdown-item"><a href="#">Language Fundamentals</a></div>
                            <div class="mega-menu-subcategory dropdown-item"><a href="#">Tkinter</a></div>
                            <div class="mega-menu-subcategory dropdown-item"><a href="#">Databse</a></div>
                        <!-- </ul> -->
                    </div>
                    <div style="margin-right: auto;">
                        <!-- <ul class="tpcategory px-0"> -->
                            <div class="dropdown-header p-2">Kotlin</div>
                            <div class="dropdown-divider m-0"></div>
                            <div class="mega-menu-subcategory dropdown-item"><a href="#">Language Fundamentals</a></div>
                        <!-- </ul> -->
                    </div>
                <div style="margin-right: auto;">
                        <!-- <ul class="tpcategory px-0"> -->
                            <div class="dropdown-header p-2">Kotlin</div>
                            <div class="dropdown-divider m-0"></div>
                            <div class="mega-menu-subcategory dropdown-item"><a href="#">Language Fundamentals</a></div>
                        <!-- </ul> -->
                    </div><div style="margin-right: auto;">
                        <!-- <ul class="tpcategory px-0"> -->
                            <div class="dropdown-header p-2">Kotlin</div>
                            <div class="dropdown-divider m-0"></div>
                            <div class="mega-menu-subcategory dropdown-item"><a href="#">Language Fundamentals</a></div>
                        <!-- </ul> -->
                    </div><div style="margin-right: auto;">
                        <!-- <ul class="tpcategory px-0"> -->
                            <div class="dropdown-header p-2">Kotlin</div>
                            <div class="dropdown-divider m-0"></div>
                            <div class="mega-menu-subcategory dropdown-item"><a href="#">Language Fundamentals</a></div>
                        <!-- </ul> -->
                    </div></div>
            </div>
     
    <!-- </div> -->
</div>
```

if you face any problem please tell

Comment: no, if one of the category has fewer sub categories, 
i want next top level category show below this category, 
in your snippet almost all of the top categories has equal sub cats,
i dont want to use flex-row in lg screens, i just want to use flex columns